# Phaser 3 is not loading the image assets

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, phaser-framework

I am following this tutorial http://phaser.io/tutorials/making-your-first-phaser-3-game/part2 and have gotten as far as loading in the sky. However, the sky image, unfortunately does not load. to verify that this is not an issue with the code, I have run the part3.html file that the tutorial provided, which says that it should load the sky from the start, to no avail. Any help is much appreciated! Thank you :)
[Image of what it looks like in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8GqK.png)

```js
<!doctype html> 
<html lang="en"> 
<head> 
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Making your first Phaser 3 Game - Part 3</title>
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.11.0/dist/phaser.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            margin: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<script type="module">

    var config = {
        type: Phaser.AUTO,
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        scene: {
            preload: preload,
            create: create,
            update: update
        }
    };

    import Phaser from 'phaser';

    var game = new Phaser.Game(config);

    function preload ()
    {
        this.load.image('sky', 'assets/sky.png');
        this.load.image('ground', 'assets/platform.png');
        this.load.image('star', 'assets/star.png');
        this.load.image('bomb', 'assets/bomb.png');
        this.load.spritesheet('dude', 'assets/dude.png', { frameWidth: 32, frameHeight: 48 });
    }

    function create ()
    {
        this.add.image(400, 300, 'sky');
    }

    function update ()
    {
    }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you using a webserver? if so which one? if you are calling the file locally it will not work. like mentioned in this article http://phaser.io/tutorials/getting-started-phaser3

Comment: btw.: you should use the newest Phaser Version 3.55.2 https://phaser.io/download/stable

Comment: I'm using the newest version of phaser, along with parcel and nodejs 
I'm new to this and am unsure if I need anything else for this to run

Comment: in your question you have a link to `phaser@3.11.0` this is not the newset version.  As mentioned in my first comment, your html page has to be on a webserver, just follow the info on the share link it explains how to set up a webserver if you don't have one running already http://phaser.io/tutorials/getting-started-phaser3/part2

Answer (score 0):

I edited your code, now you can see that your code works finely :)

Note: You have to install the live server extension for the vscode, then open the index.html file with liver server extension, and don't forget set your assets file in correct directory

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Making your first Phaser 3 Game - Part 3</title>
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.11.0/dist/phaser.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
      body {
        margin: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var config = {
        type: Phaser.AUTO,
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        scene: {
          preload: preload,
          create: create,
          update: update,
        },
      };

      var game = new Phaser.Game(config);

      function preload() {
        this.load.image("sky", "assets/sky.png");
        this.load.image("ground", "assets/platform.png");
        this.load.image("star", "assets/star.png");
        this.load.image("bomb", "assets/bomb.png");
        this.load.spritesheet("dude", "assets/dude.png", {
          frameWidth: 32,
          frameHeight: 48,
        });
      }

      function create() {
        this.add.image(400, 300, "sky");
      }

      function update() {}
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```